# SATA driver; AHCI port initialisation; Start (ST) command list;

Tags: driver, hardware, osdev, sata

I have an issue with initialising and running AHCI port on my devboard.
Processor has SATA host controller with 2 ports implemented (port 0 & port 1). SSD drive w/ SATA interface is connected to the port 1.

According to "Serial ATA AHCI 1.3.1 Specification", chapter "10.3.1 Start (PxCMD.ST)" a bunch of conditions should be satisfied before setting `PxCMD.ST` to '1'. After setting this bit, `PxCMD.CR` should be set to indicate that port is ready and runs.

**The problem is `PxCMD.CR` never comes to be set.**

State before enabling `PxCMD.ST`:

- port is in idle state, `PxCMD.ST` and `PxCMD.CR` are both '0'
- FIS Receive Enable, `PxCMD.FRE` is '1'
- Drive is connected to the port, `PxSSTS = 0x00000133` (`SSTS.IPM =
  1`, `SSTS.SPD = 3`, `SSTS.DET = 3`), `PxTFD = 0x00000150` (`TFD.STS.BSY
  = 0`, `TFD.STS.DRQ = 0`, `TFD.STS.ERR = 0`)
- `PxCLB/PxCLBU` are set with physical addresses to buffer and buffer is aligned. (1KB buffer, 1KB aligned)
- `PxCMD = 0x00404010` (`PxCMD.FBSCP = 1` & `PxCMD.FRE = 1`)

After setting `PxCMD.ST`, `PxCMD = 0x00404011` and `PxCMD.CR` stays '0'

- `PxSERR = 0` stay the same. ERR is cleaned in advance before setting `PxCMD.FRE`
- `PxSCTL = 0x00000330` (`IPM = 3`, `SPD = 3`, `DET = 0`)
- `PxTFD = 0x00000150` stay the same
- `PxSIG = 0x00000101`. The reg has `0xFFFFFFFF` when drive is not connected.

Assuming that `PxSIG` is set and `PxSERR` is '0' more likely that PLL for SATA HC is set correctly.

I have concerns about `PxTFD.ERR = 1` (when drive is disconnected `PxTFD` has default `0x7F` value and `PxTFD.ERR = 0`) but didn't find is it relevant or nor considering that still `TFD.STS.ERR = 0`

**Any ideal what is missed?**

PS: It has nothing to do w/ Linux.

Comment: Maybe you should add the exact manufacturer/model/SoC model for your devboard... As this seems to be quite near to the hardware, this might be an important detail...

Comment: Its Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ SoC and corresponding dev board 'ZCU102' (https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/ek-u1-zcu102-g.html)